# when trying to add layoutinflater with addView getting: "Skipped 63 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

Tags: android

I'm trying to add premade layout when `onItemSelected`. There is problem with the line:

```
selectLayout.addView(v);
```

When I remove this code It's running.

Logcat:

```
09-30 08:53:48.493: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-30 08:53:48.843: D/gralloc_goldfish(1033): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-30 08:53:48.963: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-30 08:54:19.894: D/dalvikvm(1033): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 82K, 7% free 2893K/3096K, paused 135ms, total 170ms
09-30 08:54:19.935: I/dalvikvm-heap(1033): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.543MB for 635812-byte allocation
09-30 08:54:20.124: D/dalvikvm(1033): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9K, 6% free 3505K/3720K, paused 183ms, total 183ms
09-30 08:54:20.864: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 129 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-30 08:54:23.363: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-30 08:54:24.215: D/AndroidRuntime(1033): Shutting down VM
09-30 08:54:24.215: W/dalvikvm(1033): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.example.fitapp.Select$1.onItemSelected(Select.java:67)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-30 08:54:24.264: E/AndroidRuntime(1033):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 08:54:28.833: I/Process(1033): Sending signal. PID: 1033 SIG: 9
09-30 08:54:32.354: I/Choreographer(1054): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-30 08:54:33.263: I/Choreographer(1054): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-30 08:54:33.363: D/gralloc_goldfish(1054): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Also here is the all of my codes.

```
package com.example.fitapp;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Select extends Activity{

    TextView tvSelect, t;
    Spinner sSelect;
    LinearLayout selectLayout;
    String[] values;
    String data;
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.select);

        selectLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.saffet);
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.second, null);

        final Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("1", "Kuvvet kazanmak istiyorsun demek?");
        map.put("2", "Kas yapmak istiyorsun demek?");
        map.put("3", "O lanet olasi yaglari eritelim!");

        Resources r = getResources();
        values = r.getStringArray(R.array.values);

        sSelect = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSelect);
        tvSelect = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelect);

        t = new TextView(Select.this);

        sSelect.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> av, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(count!=0)
                {
                    data = values[position];
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(Select.this);
                    d.setTitle("Tamam!");
                    t.setText(map.get(data));
                    t.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    d.setContentView(t);
                    d.show();

                    selectLayout.addView(v);
                }

                count = count + 1;

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Select.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/selectLayout"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Amaç Seçiniz!"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sSelect"
        android:layout_width="179dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:entries="@array/amaclar"
        android:prompt="@string/select"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use Traceview to figure out where your problem actually lies.

Comment: what is line 67 `Select.java`? You have a NPE.

Comment: there is no problem when I don't select item from spinner.

Comment: @Raghunandan selectLayout.addView(v); as I said.

Comment: @YusufAli post your `select.xml` your `selectLayout` is null

Comment: @YusufAli check my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LinearLayout id is

```
 android:id="@+id/selectLayout"
```

But you have this

```
selectLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.saffet);
```

So change to

```
selectLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.selectLayout);
```

> The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Your main thread is the ui thread. As commonsware suggested use traceview. Do you have other activities that do some intensive computation coz i don't see a lot of computation in `Select.java` . If so use a `thread` or `asynctask`.